# Make inner div 100% of outer

Tags: html, css

This is a really simple question but I can't seem to dig up the answer on how to this anywhere. Is there a way to make a nested div 100% of the outer div by using percents? The div is dynamically inserted into outer divs which are of different widths. Right now the issue I have is that it overflows out of the outer div. The current css is as such:

```
  .bottomDiv
   {
       overflow: hidden;
       height: 30px;
       bottom: 0px;
       left: 0px;
       color: red;
       position: absolute;
   }
```

The div is position on the bottom of the outer div. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: it should automatically go to 100%.

Comment: Oh, sorry I took out the 100% to see if it works. Right now it is of 0px width according to chrome. It is nested in a DIV that is floating to the left.

Comment: @DanielA.White it is positioned absolutely. So it is taken out of the "normal" flow of the document. hence it isn't full width by default.

Comment: Could you show the HTML and the CSS of both the inner and the outer divs? Even better a demo on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: remove the float and it will stertch to the width of ots parent. No width declaration required as this is default behaviour.

Comment: It is set to absolute so that I can position it at the bottom of the encapsulating div. Obviously that isn't the right way to do it, atleast not in the div.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

with this css :

```
#outer {
    position: absolute ;
    width: 50% ;
    height: 50% ;
    }

#inner {
    position: absolute ;
    bottom: 0% ;
    width: 100% ;
    height: 10% ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a very poorly put forward question and I am very sorry to those who tried to answer the question. As far as my working around the issue, it seems like setting 100% on the CSS does not solve this issue because the div is not "quite" inside the other one. Setting the div to absolute will make 100% be relative to the body rather than the wrapping div. To get around this issue your gonna need some JavaScript which dynamically appends the div and then takes the parent width an applies it to the child.

If you come across this problem, try the following (this is for multiple divs):

```
  $(".outerDiv").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<div style='width:"+ $(this).width() +"px' class='slateExpand'></div>");
  });
```

Comment: What you state "Setting the div to absolute will make 100% be relative to the body rather than the wrapping div" will only occur if your wrapping div has no `position:relative;` or `position:absolute`. What ddr2 has put forward is exactly what should solve your problem. There should be no need to fall back to javascript ... if your inner div is not quite fitting to your outer div this can be due to border, padding or margin issues?